# Create specific format string from array - jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

Its simple question

I have one jquery arrary

```
arry = [ 'apple=1', 'apple=2', 'orange=5', 'orange=7', 'orange=9', 'guava=12', 'guava=11' ];
```

I want to convert above array into string

```
str = 'apple=1*2*~orange=5*7*9~guava=12*11';
```

Kindly help me in this...

(Actually I am looking for various interesting ways to do this)

Comment: Did you attempt it yourself or no?

Comment: Yep and its working as per expectation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more straightforward ways, if you know you're going for that exact output, but I would find it most useful to first rearrange the array in to a proper dictionary:

```
var dict = {};
arry.forEach(function(item) {
   var parts = item.split('=');
   var key = parts[0];
   var value = parts[1];

   if(key in dict) {
      dict[key].push(value);
   } else {
      dict[key] = [value];
   }
});
```

... and then concatenate the string from that:

```
Object.keys(dict).map(function(key) {
   return [key, '=', dict[key].join('*')].join('');
}).join('~');
```